dynamic table comparison in powerBi
Problem - I have loaded multiple csvs in the PowerBI, These csvs columns are Filename, Mileage, City, Time etc. Multiple csvs have the similar information with little changes in terms of additional mileage, city and Time. Filenames should ideally be same but it may happen that some csvs have less rows and some have more.
I want to add 2 slicers in the dashboard for csvs version(V1, V2, V3 etc) and based on the selection in these slicer i want to compare 2 selected csv values for similar Filenames, what is the mileage and in which city and time the files are connected to.
I tried creating a dynamic table using measure (DAX) but couldn't succeed. I am not able to create a dynamic table for selection 1 csv and then one more dynamic table for selection 2(from 2nd slicer).

if you specify a folder source for your data instead of just a file (like Excel), PowerQuery will add the name of the file to the table, so then you know where each value came from once you append all the source table data together.

Just load all csvs in one table as they have the same structure. Then you’ll be able to slice, filter and analyze data in any axis
